# How can i use storyboard in Cocoa Touch Library

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, sdk, frameworks, storyboard

I have been able to build a Cocoa Touch library which I intend to use in presenting a ViewController in a storyboard, but it turns out that I can't access the storyboard. I keep getting an NSInvalidArgumentException error, reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MyStoryboard'.

```swift
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
viewController.present(cryptoTransactionViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storyboard you're trying to access isn't in your `main` bundle, it's in the framework's bundle.

So, the first thing you need to do is find the correct bundle…

```
let bundleId = "com.your.bundle.id"
guard let bundle = Bundle.allFrameworks.first(where: { $0.bundleIdentifier == bundleId}) else {
    fatalError("Failed to find bundle with identifier \(bundleId).")
}

let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: bundle)
```

Answer (score 2):

When accessing the storyboard ensure that the bundle points to the project your working on.

```
let bundleId = Bundle(identifier: "com.your.libraryBundle.id)
```

guard let bundle = Bundle.allFrameworks.first(where: { $0.bundleIdentifier == bundleId}) else {
    fatalError("Failed to find bundle with identifier (bundleId).")
} 
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyLibraryStoryboard", bundle: bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Here you access the storyboard from main bundle of the app `Bundle.main` and for sure doesn't exist , hence the crash

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

you need to access the library's bundle , so try

```
let libBundle = Bundle(identifier:"com.library")
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle:libBundle)
```